# How can I read the gradle sonar runner properties from a gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am writing a custom Gradle plugin that applies the Gradle sonar runner plugin and defaults some of the parameters. I want to write a test to confirm that the properties are set correctly, but I cannot figure out how to access the data after it is set.

I tried `project.getExtensions().sonarRunner.sonarProperties.getProperties()` and a few variants, but this either throws a null pointer or returns something other than the sonar properties.

Is it possible to read the sonar properties after they are set? How?

Comment: Basically all the properties should be accessible via `project.propertyName`.  Have you tried?

Comment: @Opal I have tried ` project.'sonar.host.url'` and ` project.sonar.host.url` and neither one has worked. I have also tried  `project.sonarRunner.sonarProperties`, but `sonarProperties` "could not be found".

Comment: What are the properties you are trying to set on the SQ plugin? If this is not too specific we could maybe improve the SQ plugin to support your use case natively?

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam Hello Julien, I am using my custom plugin to set the host url as well as all of the necessary jdbc properties (url, driver class, username and password). I am also defaulting sonar analysis mode and some `issuesReport` properties.

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam I do not have any trouble setting sonar properties via a plugin in, my issues is that I cannot read them back out again to verify that they have been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our own tests we are using a "secret" property that will dump all SQ properties in a file so that you can write assertions on it.

`-DsonarRunner.dumpToFile=out.properties`

See for example how I wrote integration tests for the new Gradle SonarQube plugin:
https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-gradle/blob/master/integrationTests/src/test/java/org/sonarqube/gradle/GradleTest.java#L22

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, just remember to pass in the property key with quotes:

```
project.tasks.sonarRunner.sonarProperties.get("sonar.host.url")
```